# Output is not in correct format

Tags: python, count, numbers, output, python-3.7

I need to print all the prime numbers in a range. But the out put must be like in 1 line and for some reason I cannot use list or .append or even .join. 
Ex the range is 8 to 20, the output would be : `"The prime number(s) in this range are 11, 13, 17, 19`

My code right now is:

```
start_range = int(input("Enter the first number in the range"))
end_range = int(input("Enter the number in the end of the range"))

for integer in range(start_range, end_range + 1):
        count = 0
        for prime in range(2, integer+1):#This loop is from part 1 and will tell if the number is prime or not
            if (integer % prime) == 0:
                count = count + 1
                if count > 2 and count != 1:
                    break
        else:
         print("The prime number(s) in this range are", integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the integers to a list, then when you print it out use

```
print(f"The prime number(s) in this range are {','.join(integer_list)}")
```